# Метод getInfo(), как тебя реализовать?

Tags: php, ооп

Метод **getInfo()** в классе **SuperUser** должен возвращать ассоциативный массив, в котором именами элементов массива являются *имена свойств объект*а, а значениями элементов - *значения свойств объекта*.

Как можно реализовать?

```
// абстрактный класс UserAbstract
abstract class UserAbstract {
    public $name;
    public $login;
    public $password;

    function __construct($name, $login, $pass){
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> login = $login;
        $this -> password = $pass;
    }

    function __destruct(){
        echo "Пользователь {$this->login} удален!";
    }

    // абстрактный метод
    abstract function showInfo();
}

class User extends UserAbstract{
    public $surname;

    // реализация абстрактного метода
    function showInfo(){
        echo "Name: {$this->name}\n Surname: {$this->surname}\n Login: {$this->login}\n Password: {$this->password}\n";
    }
}


// интерфейс ISuperUser
interface ISuperUser{
    // объявлен метод getInfo
    function getInfo();
}

// класс superUser наследует класс User и реализует интерфейс ISuperUser
class superUser extends User implements ISuperUser{
    function getInfo(){
        // вернуть ассоциативный массив, в котором именами элементов массива являются имена свойств объекта, а значениями элементов -значения свойств объекта

    }
}


$superUser = new superUser("Jack", "lucky_jack", 777);
$superUser -> surname = "Luckie";
$superUser -> showInfo();
```

Comment: читайте доки: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php

Comment: Спасибо, но я только осваиваю PHP и ООП. Нужен простой пример на приведенном коде.

Comment: именно поэтому вместо готового кода я вам дал ссылку. Дорогу осилит идущий, удачи

Comment: И не поспоришь!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInfo(){

    $rc = new ReflectionClass($this);
    $attributes = $rc->getProperties();
    
    $result = [];
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $name = $attribute->getName();
        $result[$name] = $this->{$name};
    }
    
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 0):

в самом простом случае можно сделать

```
return (array)$this;
```

публичные свойства будут получены с нормальными именами ключей, для приватных префиксом будет являться имя класса, а у протектед - звездочка.

Comment: можно еще дичь какую-нить написать а-ля `return json_decode(json_encode($this), true)`, но не надо )

Comment: Информативно! Спасибо))